# TypeError: undefined is not an object when using information from one page to another

Tags: angular

I am struggling with getting a news article to pull through from the news page (all articles displayed) to the news-detail page (when you click read more on a particular article).

The code for the news-detail.html is

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
<ion-back-button slot="start" defaultHref="/news"></ion-back-button>
<ion-title>{{ news.title }}</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

the error is TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ctx.news.title')

the news-detail.page.ts code is:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { News } from '../news.model';
import { NewsService } from '../news.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {
NavController,
ModalController,
ActionSheetController
} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
selector: 'app-news-detail',
templateUrl: './news-detail.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./news-detail.page.scss'],
})
export class NewsDetailPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
news: News;
private newsSub: Subscription;

constructor(
private NewsService: NewsService,
private navCtrl: NavController,
private route: ActivatedRoute,

) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
  if (!paramMap.has('newsId')) {
    this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/news/news-detail');
    return;
  }

this.newsSub = this.NewsService.getNews(paramMap.get('newsId')).subscribe(news => {
  this.news = news;
});
});
}
ngOnDestroy() {
if (this.newsSub) {
this.newsSub.unsubscribe();
}}}
```

the news.service.ts code is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { News } from './news.model';
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsService {

private _news = new BehaviorSubject<News[]> ([
new News(
  '1',
  'Test News Article',
  'This is the first news article!!',
  'Jesus Green, Cambridge',
  '17/05/2021',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Green_tick.svg',
  'Marco'
  
),
new News(
  '2',
  'Test News Article 2',
  'This is the second news article!!',
  'Harpenden, Rothamsted',
  '17/05/2021',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Green_tick.svg',
  'Jon'
  
)
]);

get news() {
return this._news.asObservable();
}

constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

getNews(id: string) {
return this.news.pipe(
  take(1), 
map(news => { 
  return { ...news.find(p => p.id === id) };
}));
}

addNews(
title: string,
story: string,
venue: string,
date: string,

) {
const newNews = new News(
  Math.random().toString(),
  title,
  story,
  'https://lonelyplanetimages.imgix.net/mastheads/GettyImages-538096543_medium.jpg?   
sharp=10&vib=20&w=1200',
  venue,
  date,
  this.authenticationService.userId
);

this.news.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(news => {
this._news.next(news.concat(newNews));
});
}}
```

the news.page.ts code is:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from './news.service';
import { News } from './news.model';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs'


@Component({
selector: 'app-news',
templateUrl: './news.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./news.page.scss'],
})
export class NewsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
loadedNews: News[];
private newsSub: Subscription;

constructor(private NewsService: NewsService, private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.newsSub = this.NewsService.news.subscribe(news => {
  this.loadedNews = news;
});
}

ngOnDestroy() {
if (this.newsSub) {
  this.newsSub.unsubscribe();
}}}
```

any suggestions would be hugely appreciated. if I need to upload any of the other files happy to as well. The news page.html works fine and loads the news.
many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. At the creation of the component, the variable `news` is still `undefined` as it's not yet initialized in the subscription. But seeing that the variable is used only to render, you could get the value in the template using `async` pipe instead. This will also mitigate the need to unsubscribe in the component.
2. Use `switchMap` operator instead of nested subscriptions.

Try the following

**Controller**

```js
import { Observable, NEVER } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class NewsDetailPage implements OnInit {
  public news$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private NewsService: NewsService,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.news$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((paramMap: any) => {    // <-- opening brace here
        if (paramMap.has('newsId')) {
          return this.NewsService.getNews(paramMap.get('newsId'));
        }
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/news/news-detail');
        return NEVER;
      })                        // <-- closing brace here
    );
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(news$ | async) as news">
  <ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-back-button slot="start" defaultHref="/news"></ion-back-button>
      <ion-title>{{ news.title }}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Michael, just trying to implement it but it comes up with an error message '{' expected on the "if" statement in ngOnInIt?

Comment: @Jon: I missed the curly braces for the `switchMap`. I've updated the answer. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: thanks, step forward, no error messages but the news-detail in blank, no error messages in the console log either!

Comment: Are you sure the HTTP request is returning a valid response? How does it look in the browser's network option? What type of data does the API return? If it other than a JSON, the `responseType` must be set explicitly in the request.

Comment: Thanks Michael, sorry am new to this and following or trying to, an online tutorial! I haven’t set up the http request yet, just using the test articles above which are in the news.service.ts code above? Have I missed something to check? Thanks for help much appreciated!